# Normalization of Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-normalization

Kindly need your help in solving the normalization issue of tables as I a new to SQL.I have five tables.

```
Table1-->Column1,Column2.
Table2-->Column3,Column4.
Table3-->Column5,Column6,Column3.
Table4-->Column7,Column8,Column5.
Table5-->Column9,Column10,Column11,Column12,Column1,Column5,Column7.
```

Here Column1,column3,Column5,Column7 and Column9 are primary key and Column1,Column5 and Column7 are foreign keys for Table5 and my entries from PHP will be to Table5. The issue is I am getting duplicate entries to the Table5. There will be multiple entries to Table5 in a day.I want to give (Column1 and Column7) as a unique key .Is there any way to give unique key for 2 combined Foreign keys. I tried,

```
 Alter Table Table5 Add UNIQUE KEY(Column1,Column7);
```

but getting error as duplicate value for column1.
This is a in house application so running on XAMPP and data is entered by different systems via LAN and is saved in local server.Is this causing any issue.Please help in solving the issue as more than 1000 data is entered in a day.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to use meaningful names in your examples. It's much easier to read then Column1....Column12

Comment: . Please read & act on [mcve]. Give exact DDL, error messages, table contents, etc. Read the official documentation re UNIQUE indexes & FKs. If you are wrongly getting duplicate entries in 5, preventing them from being inserted only solves part of the problem. Why does this happen? What should be happening? PS This is not normalization. What do you think that word means?

Comment: So you run that ALTER TABLE statement and get an error that there are duplicates in the table? Then first remove the duplicates and then run the statement.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider to make a composite key on Table5 like this:
instead of Column9 as a primary key use Column1,Column5,Column7 as a composite key.